# Finding a Consistent Estimator

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

> **Question:** Let $r_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $p = P(r_t \leq -r_T) = F(-r_T)$. Suppose that $p=.05$, and we want to find a
>   consistent estimator for $r_T$.

So far, I have that

$$\begin{align*}
.05 &= P\left(\frac{r_t - \mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{-r_T - \mu}{\sigma}\right) \\
&= P\left(Z \leq \frac{-r_T - \mu}{\sigma}\right) \\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{-r_T - \mu}{\sigma}\right) \\
&= 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{r_T + \mu}{\sigma}\right)
\end{align*}$$

How do we decide on a consistent estimator given $\Phi\left(\frac{r_T + \mu}{\sigma}\right)$? The sample mean of $r_t$ seems like a decent candidate, since that is a consistent estimator (because $r_t$ is normal). However, don't we need to take .05 into consideration somehow?

If it helps any, this question is within the domain of financial economics, where $r_t$ is log-returns of a specific asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your derivations, $r_T=-\mu-\Phi^{-1}(0.05)\sigma$. Thus, 
$$
\hat{r}_T=-\hat{\mu}-\Phi^{-1}(0.05)\hat{\sigma}
$$
is consistent if $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ are consistent estimators of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.